# MultiPowUpload (flash file upload component) giving Error #2049 while uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: jquery, file-upload, amazon-s3, swfupload

Using [MultiPowUpload](http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx) (flash file upload component) to Upload files to [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

I just use the **flash_amazons3generator.html** file to generate the "S3 Policy and Signature" to paste in var **flashvars = {}**.

But when I tried to upload it giving me "**Error #2049**".

Here is my **S3 Policy and Signature**:

```
 var flashvars = {
      "uploadUrl": "http://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
      "amazonS3.accessKeyId": "xxxxxx",
      "amazonS3.policy": "xxxxxx",
      "amazonS3.signature": "xxxxx",
      "amazonS3.acl": "public-read-write",
      "amazonS3.key": "xxxxx"
 };
```

I also tried to use 'encodeURI' and 'encodeURIComponent' method, may be its a problem due to Encoding but no avail:

```
 'policy': encodeURI(data.policy)
 'signature': encodeURIComponent(data.signature)
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?.

Comment: [This](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=910) thread is also similar to my problem. Here is my `crossdomain.xml` file code:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>`.

I placed the following `crossdomain.xml` file at: `myBucket`'s root. But still `Error #2049` is comming.

Comment: Similar problem is also reported at [Amazon Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=110865), but I didn't get any sufficient answer. Any one have an idea, what the solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution where its is going wrong. The solution is I'm missing one important thing. That I should set the content type for crossdomain.xml file to text/xml.

The following image will help. How to set that:
[image: crossdomain.xml file to text/xml]

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you should place crossdomain.xml file at the root of your bucket in order to allow MultiPowUpload upload files into this bucket. 
And grant 'public-read' permissions to this file. Read more about crossdomain security policy at MultiPowUpload documentation.

You can read more in tutorial 
http://www.element-it.com/OnlineHelpMulti/Tutorial.html#amazon

Here you can see that upload to S3 server work correctly:
demo.element-it.com/Examples/MultiPow/flash_uploadtoamazons3.html

Also you can grab crossdomain.xml from elemen-it s3 bucket:
http://element-it.s3.amazonaws.com/crossdomain.xml

Feel free to contact Element-IT support team if you have any questions related to our products.

Comment: Thanks Viktor for your help. I already did exactly what you are saying. After all that precautions I'm still getting `Error #2049` while uploading files to Amazon S3.